# How to execute tasks on another host beside the target host in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I would like to run a playbook with serval tasks on the target host 'A'. Additionally I would like to set a DNS record for host 'A' at the DNS server host 'B'.
Preferably only one playbook shall be used. Hosts of the play will be set to 'all', the play to set DNS records will be limited to Host 'B'. Host 'B' will also be fixed and could be hardcoded, it should use eg. ansible_hostname of Host 'A' as parameter.
Any Idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`delegate_to`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation).

```
- name: set dns record
  win_dns_record:
    name: "{{ inventory_hostname_short }}"
    type: A
    value: "{{ item }}"
    zone: "{{ ansible_domain }}"
  delegate_to: 'b'
  loop: "{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}"
```

The task will loop over all IP addresses of the machine and run against 'B' to create DNS entries. Probably not the best configuration, but it shows everything you need.

Comment: Awesome, I wasn't aware delegate_to can be used in this way. I added also delegate_facts: True to delegate Host 'A' facts to Host 'B'.